# How to update a table column based on the condition of two other table columns using st_contains()

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I'm attempting to update a table column based on the st_contains() results using two other tables. The code I've written below returns too many results. What do I need to change to make this work?

```
UPDATE "PRIMARY_USE_DESC"."CAD_Primary_Desc" SET "Parcel_Desc" = 'PARK'
WHERE (
    SELECT geom_poly
    FROM "Buda_Parks" t1
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT geom_point 
        FROM "HCAD_POINTS"
    ) t2 ON ST_Contains(t1.geom_poly, t2.geom_point)
) IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. Posting it here in case someone else has this question.

```
UPDATE "PRIMARY_USE_DESC"."CAD_Primary_Desc" 
Set "Parcel_Desc" = 'PARK' 
FROM
 (select geom_poly from "Buda_Parks" t1
 left join (SELECT geom_point FROM "HCAD_POINTS") t2 on ST_Contains(geom_poly,geom_point)) t3
 WHERE ST_Contains(geom_poly, geom_point)
```